# Office365 Users query returns Photo as null

Tags: office365, office365api

Trying to retrieve a list of users on a domain using Microsoft.Graph library:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();
var request = graphClient.Users.Request().Select("businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName, photo");
var ListOfUsers = await request.GetAsync();
```

And the scope is:

```
Scope = "openid email profile offline_access User.Read User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All " + graphScopes,
```

The photo field is always null. What is the correct way to retrieve the photos for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate endpoint to fetch the photo for the user

```
graphClient.Users[<UserPrincipalName>].Photo.Content.Request()
```

Please refer [this](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get) link

Comment: How do I get a remote url for the picture?